# Identify components in an audio circuit schematic

Tags: audio, schematics, vintage

In the attached image you can see a circuit part of a commercial audio amplifier. I'm trying to determine what kind of component is `R-CH` and what role it plays in the circuit. I'd also like to figure out whether this circuit is on the audio signal path of the amplifier or not. What clues would give that away?

[image: PB-1122A pcb]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I'm trying to determine what kind of component is R-CH and what role
> it plays in the circuit.*

`R-CH` is the right-hand channel. Above it you see the circuit for the left-hand channel. The total circuit is for a stereo amplifier of some sort that has left and right channels.

They don't bother showing the right-hand circuit details because it's a repeat of the left-hand circuit.